# How to ignore subqueries if they return no rows without effecting the rest of the query output Postgresql 12.3

Tags: python, html, postgresql, select, where-clause

I have written an app which takes input from the user through an HTML page (for the problem part, it is just 4 tick boxes) into to a python app which sends a query though psycopg2 to PostgreSQL and returns a dict list which is render back to HTML for the user using flask.

Everything works as long as the columns which the user selects(by wanting live music for example) are correct within the database/sql query, if not I get a blank output. (hope this makes some sense).

*code*

this is how I create each of the sub queries depending on input of the user

```
    if request.form.get("latenight"):
   latenight = True
   latenight = " AND '23:00:00'>={} AND {}<= '04:00:00'".format(dayclose,dayclose)
else:
    latenight =""
if request.form.get("food_avail"):
    food_avail = True
    food_avail =" AND LOCALTIME(0) BETWEEN {} AND {}".format(restdayopen, restdayclose)
else:
    food_avail=""
if request.form.get("livemusic"):
    livemusic = True
    livemusic = " AND LOCALTIME(0) BETWEEN {} AND {}".format(musicdaybegin, musicdayfinish)
else:
    livemusic=""
if request.form.get("camra"):
    camra = True
    camquery = " AND camra = True"
else:
    camra = False
    camquery = ""
```

this is then shown in the query statement which is passed to postgresql

```
query = """SELECT name_, address, postcode, latitude, longitude, pubid, monclose,
             monopen, tueopen, tueclose, wedopen, wedclose, thuropen, thurclose, friopen, friclose, satopen,
             satclose, sunopen, sunclose,
             restopenmon, restclosemon, restopentue, restopenwed, restopenthur, restopenfri, restopensat,
             restopensun, restclosetue, restclosewed, restclosethur, restclosefri, restclosesat, restclosesun,
             active, musicbeginmon, musicbegintue,
             musicbeginwed, musicbeginthur, musicbeginfri, musicbeginsat, musicbeginsun, musicfinishmon,
             musicfinishtue, musicfinishwed, musicfinishthur, musicfinishfri, musicfinishsat, musicfinishsun, camra, ROUND(distance::NUMERIC , 2) distance
               FROM (
               SELECT z.name_,
               z.address,z.tueopen,
               z.camra, z.monopen,
               z.postcode, z.monclose,
               z.satclose, z.pubid,
               z.latitude, z.longitude,
               z.tueclose, z.wedopen, z.wedclose,
               z.thuropen, z.thurclose, z.friopen,
               z.friclose, z.satopen, z.sunopen, z.sunclose,
               z.restopenmon, z.restclosemon, z.restopentue, z.restopenwed, z.restopenthur, 
               z.restopenfri, z.restopensat, z.restopensun, z.restclosetue, z.restclosewed, z.restclosethur, 
               z.restclosefri, z.restclosesat, z.restclosesun, z.active, z.musicbeginmon, z.musicbegintue,
               z.musicbeginwed, z.musicbeginthur, z.musicbeginfri, z.musicbeginsat, z.musicbeginsun, z.musicfinishmon,
               z.musicfinishtue, z.musicfinishwed, z.musicfinishthur, z.musicfinishfri, z.musicfinishsat, 
               z.musicfinishsun,
               p.radius,
               p.distance_unit
                        * DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                        * COS(RADIANS(z.latitude))
                       * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint - z.longitude))
                       + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                       * SIN(RADIANS(z.latitude))))) AS distance
               FROM pubs AS z 
               JOIN (SELECT """ + latbx + """ AS latpoint, """ + lonbx + """AS longpoint,
                    100 AS radius,      69 AS distance_unit
               ) AS p ON 1=1 
               WHERE z.latitude
               BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
               AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
               AND z.longitude
               BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
               AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
                ) AS d
               WHERE distance <= radius AND distance <""" + miles_ + """"""+camquery+""""""+latenight+""""""+food_avail+""""""+livemusic+"""
               ORDER BY distance """
```

It seems to be that if either latenight, food_avail or livemusic is not satisfied then it returns no rows at all, which with the AND statements is correct.

What I need to do is return all rows which fit any of the criteria and if possible get a message sent back to python which allows me to grab it and use it to display something to the user ("no live music available").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that your `pubs` table is not normalized makes this much more difficult than it should be.  Please let me know if you are interested in tackling that.

The short answer is that rather than put these criteria in the `WHERE` clause, they should be put into the `SELECT` list.

For instance, a checked checkbox for "latenight" would show up as:

```
  select . . .,
         1 as latenight_checked,
         case 
           when localtime(0) between 'restopentue' and 'restclosetue' then 1 
           else 0
         end as latenight,
         . . .
```

If it's not checked you do this:

```
  select . . .,
         0 as latenight_checked,
         case 
           when localtime(0) between 'restopentue' and 'restclosetue' then 1 
           else 0
         end as latenight,
         . . .
```

Do something similar for "food_avail", "livemusic", and "camra".

This will return whether something is true for a pub and whether the user cared about that criterion that you can use in your code.

**Update with better illustration:**

```
latenight_cb = (1 if request.form.get("latenight") else 0)

latenight_sql = "case when '23:00:00' >={} AND {}<= '04:00:00' then 1 else 0 end as latenight, {} as latenight_checked,".format(dayclose, dayclose, latenight_cb)
```

Then, in your query:

```
query = """SELECT name_, address, postcode, latitude, longitude, 
                  pubid, monclose, monopen, tueopen, tueclose, wedopen, 
     -- Lines snipped here
                  musicfinishfri, musicfinishsat, musicfinishsun, camra,
                  """ + latenight_sql + """
                  ROUND(distance::NUMERIC , 2) distance
```

When your results come back, you will be able to see whether the pub is open late in `latenight` and whether the form had that box checked in `latenight_checked`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know the database itself is a mess, but it is test data on a system I am using purely to try and build this app, there is a lot more going to be added before this is finished and I will be ripping the db up and redoing it so for now it will do. i have looked at your response and have searched around and I am not sure how I am suppose to implement this (sorry). The reason I was using the where is so that the result would do something like : search for pubs within X distance, then see if they had the users requirements and if not just let them know what they did have.

Comment: Also I am not really worried about finding out the information if they didn't ask for it.

Comment: @JamesD  I put a better illustration in my answer.  You can choose not to put the extra SQL in the query's `SELECT` list if the boxes are not checked, but it costs you the same to bring it back every time you run this query.

Comment: @ Mike.. Thanks for the illustration, it makes perfect sense and is working like a charm! I am very grateful for all your help.